# pandas: finding the average of a selected column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, mean

Here's first 15 elements of my DataFrame

What I need is average (column(Total Rainfall) per year(column (Year). The Dataset I have contains this rainfall up to 2011.

Could anyone help with this?

Later I want to plot the average per year from 1962 to 2011.

```
In [143]: df.head(15)

Out[143]:

   Total Rainfall       Year  
0           134.6       1962  
1            77.2       1962  
2            73.6       1962  
3            68.6       1962  
4            80.7       1962  
5            50.2       1962  
6            92.2       1962  
7            99.4       1962  
8           122.4       1962  
9            42.6       1962  
10          105.5       1962  
11           86.4       1962  
12           34.8       1963  
13           96.0       1963  
14          212.5       1963
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for this. Using the data you've supplied:

```
 >>> df.groupby('Year').mean()
        Rainfall
Year            
1962   86.116667
1963  114.433333
```

Pandas' `groupby` method groups a DataFrame by values in a specific column(s) and aggregates numerical data in the other columns with a particular function(s) (in this case `mean`).

To plot this data, you could use `plot` and specify the kind of chart you want:

```
>>> df.groupby('Year').mean().plot(kind='bar');
```

Which produces this bar chart:

[image]

Comment: I knew it was simple! Thank you very much ajcr.